# Inserting into a Postgres Array from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am very new to Rails, I want to be able to insert names into an array attached to my user.

I added an empty array called '**subscribed_tasks**' to my '**schema.rb**'

And I wondered how I can push data into that array.

My first attempt was:

Having '`= link_to "Subscribe", subscribe_task_path, class: "btn btn-default"`' in my **show.haml** and then having this within my **route.rb**:

```
 resources :tasks do
    member do
        get :subscribe
    end
  end
```

& then adding this to my Tasks_Controller:

```
def subscribe
    @user = current_user
    @user.subscribed_tasks << @task.title
    redirect_to @task, notice: "Subscribed to "+ @task.title
end
```

The problems I'm facing are:

How do I pass the task they're subscribing to's parameters to the controller so then the correct data can be pushed into the array. Also, I don't think I'm finding the array correctly.

All in all, what I'm programming is a mess, am I missing something fundamental about Rails and is there an entirely better way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the output of `rake route`. Why are you doing `@user.subscribed_tasks << @task.title` instead of `current_user.subscribed_tasks << @task`

Comment: @Antarr Byrd I didn't know you could do that straight off, shows my inexperience! The response I'm getting from `rake route` is `rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'route'` so I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry I meant `rake routes` . Also you probably need post route to go with your get

Comment: Hard to format with the character limits. I'll gist it.

Comment: @AntarrByrd https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6c199d4b2d79203f55b

Comment: The [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) gem will probably make you life much easier.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thanks for that, I'll get reading.